# Rewrite below logic without linq

Tags: c#, linq

Can some body help me with the following? this is an interview question.

```
Rewrite this to not use LINQ or Lambda.
// pseudo code for reference
class Person { int Age; List<Person> Children; }

List<Person> items;

// linq / lambda example
var total = items.SelectMany(i => i.Children).Sum(i => i.Age);
```

Comment: what effort have you made?

Comment: Have you tried to compile the code you posted?

Comment: I realize this is an interview question and doesn't need to make sense, but what are you going to do with the sum of the ages of the children of a group of people?

Answer (score 2):

Let's break it down.

1. Generally any LINQ operation on a collection can be replaced with a `foreach` loop.

   ```
   // items
   foreach (var item in items)
   {
       // ...
   }
   ```
2. `SelectMany()` corresponds to an inner `foreach` on the selected items.

   ```
   // items
   foreach (var item in items)
   {
       // .SelectMany(i => i.Children)
       foreach (var child in item.Children)
       {
           // ...
       }
   }
   ```
3. The last operation is your result.  You are taking the `Sum()` of the `Age` of the child items.

   ```
   int sum = 0;
   // items
   foreach (var item in items)
   {
       // .SelectMany(i => i.Children)
       foreach (var child in item.Children)
       {
           // .Sum(i => i.Age)
           sum += child.Age;
       }
   }
   // result is in sum
   ```

Comment: Thanks Jeff Mercado, the way of you explained it step wise,is very clear.